# SQLCommand.CommanText: The CommandText property has not been properly initialized

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell

I'm trying to load data in a mysql db with powershell.

I got this error: The `CommandText` property has not been properly initialized.

Here is my Code:

```
$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $conn
$Command.CommandText = $strquery
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
$Datatable.Load($Reader)
```

And this is `$strquery` (checked with debugger):

```
"LOAD DATA INFILE '"+$tbx_pfad.Text +"' INTO TABLE login FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 LINES(logins.user, logins.pc, logins.ts, logins.dc, @var1, @var2) SET now = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, logins.time = CONCAT(@var1,' ',REPLACE(@var2,'-',':'))"
```

And connection also works.

The problem is that after this line:

`$Command.CommandText = $strquery`

`$Command.CommandText` is still empty.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you :)

Comment: SQLClient.SQLCommand is for [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-2016), not [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com). (["The System.Data.SqlClient namespace is the.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx)). It won't be able to connect to a MySQL server.

Comment: Oh thanks. I use now: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand :)

Comment: Perhaps, OleDBConnection and corresponding command class would work if the proper driver exists on your client system.